# WordPress не приходит письмо для подтверждения аккаунта при регистрации

Tags: php, wordpress, email

Есть сайт на WordPress на котором я недавно обнаружил что не приходят сообщения с текстом для активации аккаунта. То есть пользователи не могут зарегистрироваться на сайте. Я уже много сайтов перелистал, пробовал разные плагины, пока не помогает. Думаю я просто чего-то не понимаю, точнее ничего в отправке эмейлов, никогда не практиковал..

Вы не могли бы мне поэтапно помочь настроить это?

Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: написать простой скрипт из [примеров](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php). Если письма не отправляются - пишите хостеру, т.к. у вас не настроена отправка мыла на самом сервере, либо php не знает как правильно их отправлять, что тоже можно к настройке отнести, а значит надо просить хостера (раз сами не можете)

Comment: Я про то, что в WordPress наверняка встроена функция, но я не знаю где и как понять работает ли она. Хостера спрошу про поддержку mail() и немного информации про аккаунт POP3.

Comment: WordPress в любом случае в конце концов использует функцию `mail()`. Она может быть обернута подготовкой красивых писем и тому подобными рюшами, но заменить ее может только smtp-сервер, а настроек для работы с ним в WP штатно нет.

Comment: @Andrew Nikolsky Я понял. Мне сказали что функция mail() была заблокирована на моем хостинге, не подскажете что такое и как работает SMTP? Почти все плагины на эту тему используют эту технологию, а я понятия не имею как настроить. Вообще супер будет если представите ссылку на понятный гайд, если такая у вас есть под рукой...

Comment: Предлагаю установить этот плагин: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-bank/

Comment: @s976 , знаете что самое интересное? Он у меня уже был скачан, просто я был так морально опущен что даже не опробовал его после десятка предыдущих. Но есть проблема, для того что бы использовать SMTP google нужно обязательно иметь приложение в Google Apps? Иначе система блокирует вход в аккаунт и мне на запасную почту пришло об этом оповещение.

Comment: Не нужно Google Apps. Сделайте себе почту для вашего домена через  [Яндекс](https://pdd.yandex.ru)

Comment: @s976, хорошо, и тем не менее, ведь столько плагинов на WordPress используют Gmail SMTP и все они не работают? Наверняка же есть решение?

Comment: Почему не работают? Работают и еще как. Можно посылать и через обычный аккаунт gmail. Но будет видно, что почта приходит с него. Также придется ввести пароль этого аккаунта на админке. Как хотите.

Comment: @s976, а как такое сделать? Я это и хотел сделать, специально ящик регистрировал.

Comment: Не понял. Что именно Вы хотите сделать?

Comment: @s976, я хочу что бы работала почта от Gmail, мне все-равно на то будет ли виден адрес или имя и т. д. Просто почта от гугл выглядит приемлемо для меня, в отличии от Яндекса. +она, как бы, глобальна и отлично вольется в интернациональный сайт, а Яндекс русский, и не совсем отлично.

Comment: Ну так в чем проблема? Настраивайте плагин. Должно работать. [Там на скриншотах](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-bank/screenshots/) видно как настроить для Гугля.

Comment: Я создам новый тикет на эту тему...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема действительно в хостинге. Они не поддерживают функцию `mail()` в бесплатном тарифе из-за огромного количества спамеров, использующих сервера под свои мерзкие дела. В общем, советую обратиться в поддержку за информацией и перейти на платный тариф для поддержки функции (скорее всего там она будет работать).

Answer (score 1):

**!Возможна** проблема с хостингом. Если это тестовый период хостинга, то, возможно, в демо режиме (Smtp настройки) хостинга вам не доступны. Также и с бесплатным хостингом.

Вы можете решить вопрос с хостером и это бесплатно. Напишите в Техподержку. Если проблема в другом то пишите, постараюсь ответить.